# DirectX 11 throws out my pixel shader when I multiply verts by MVP

Tags: directx, directx11, hlsl

Been following some tutorials online for DirectX 11. I was able to successfully get a triangle to render in screen space. But the moment I add a MVP matrix, my triangle disappears!

Looking at it in the graphical debugger that ships with VS2015, I can see my render pipeline is just skipping my pixel shader entirely, but I have no idea why!

my code:
    #include "stdafx.h"

```
#include "graphics.h"

#include "types.h"

#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#include <DirectXMath.h>
//#include <DirectXPackedVector.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dcompiler.lib")

namespace graphics {

    IDXGISwapChain *swap_chain;
    ID3D11Device *device;
    ID3D11DeviceContext *context;
    ID3D11RenderTargetView *back_buffer;

    ID3D11Texture2D *depth_stencil_buffer;
    ID3D11DepthStencilState *depth_stencil_state;
    ID3D11DepthStencilView *depth_stencil_view;

    ID3D11VertexShader *sh_vertex;
    ID3D11PixelShader *sh_pixel;
    ID3D11Buffer *vertex_buffer;
    ID3D11Buffer *index_buffer;
    ID3D11Buffer *shader_constants;
    camera main_camera;

    ID3D11InputLayout *layout;

    struct vertex {
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
        D3DCOLORVALUE color;
    };


    HRESULT compile_shader(LPCWSTR file, LPCSTR entry_point, LPCSTR features, ID3DBlob** program);
    void init_pipeline();
    void init_graphics();
    void build_shader_constants();
    void build_depth_stencil(unsigned int width, unsigned int height);

    void init(HWND hWnd, int width, int height) {
        DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC description;
        ZeroMemory(&description, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

        description.BufferCount = 1;
        description.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
        description.BufferDesc.Width = width;
        description.BufferDesc.Height = height;
        description.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
        description.OutputWindow = hWnd;
        description.SampleDesc.Count = 4;
        description.Windowed = TRUE;
        description.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;

        D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL,
            D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
            NULL,
            D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
            &description,
            &swap_chain,
            &device,
            NULL,
            &context);

        ID3D11Texture2D *buffer_texture;
        swap_chain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&buffer_texture);
        device->CreateRenderTargetView(buffer_texture, NULL, &back_buffer);
        buffer_texture->Release();

        context->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &back_buffer, NULL);

        D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
        ZeroMemory(&viewport, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));

        viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
        viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
        viewport.Width = (float)width;
        viewport.Height = (float)height;
        viewport.MinDepth = 0;
        viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0;

        context->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

        init_pipeline();
        init_graphics();
        build_depth_stencil(width, height);

        main_camera.position = DirectX::XMFLOAT3(-1000.0f, -1000.0f, -1000.0f);
        main_camera.look_at = DirectX::XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        main_camera.aspect_ratio = (float)width / (float)height;
        main_camera.fov = DirectX::XM_PIDIV4;
        main_camera.near_clip = 1.f;
        main_camera.far_clip = 10000.0f;
    }

    void render() {
        float color[4] = { 0.0f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 1.0f };
        context->ClearRenderTargetView(back_buffer, color);
        context->ClearDepthStencilView(depth_stencil_view, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0xFF);

        unsigned int stride = sizeof(vertex);
        unsigned int offset = 0;

        build_shader_constants();

        context->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &shader_constants);
        context->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &vertex_buffer, &stride, &offset);
        context->IASetIndexBuffer(index_buffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);
        context->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D10_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
        context->Draw(3, 0);

        swap_chain->Present(0, 0);
    }

    struct vs_constants {
        DirectX::XMFLOAT4X4 model;
        DirectX::XMFLOAT4X4 view;
        DirectX::XMFLOAT4X4 projection;
    };

    DirectX::XMVECTOR up = DirectX::XMVectorSet(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);

    DirectX::XMMATRIX create_view_matrix(const DirectX::XMFLOAT3 &position, const DirectX::XMFLOAT3 &look) {
        DirectX::XMVECTOR eye_position = DirectX::XMLoadFloat3(&position);
        DirectX::XMVECTOR look_at = DirectX::XMLoadFloat3(&look);

        return DirectX::XMMatrixLookAtLH(eye_position, look_at, up);
    }
    void build_shader_constants() {

        D3D11_BUFFER_DESC buffer_desc;
        buffer_desc.ByteWidth = sizeof(vs_constants);
        buffer_desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
        buffer_desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
        buffer_desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
        buffer_desc.MiscFlags = 0;
        buffer_desc.StructureByteStride = 0;

        vs_constants constants;
        DirectX::XMStoreFloat4x4(&constants.model, DirectX::XMMatrixIdentity());
        DirectX::XMStoreFloat4x4(&constants.view, DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose(create_view_matrix(main_camera.position, main_camera.look_at)));
        DirectX::XMStoreFloat4x4(&constants.projection, DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose(DirectX::XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(main_camera.fov, main_camera.aspect_ratio, main_camera.near_clip, main_camera.far_clip)));

        D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA constant_data;
        constant_data.pSysMem = &constants;
        constant_data.SysMemPitch = 0;
        constant_data.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

        HRESULT hr = device->CreateBuffer(&buffer_desc, &constant_data, &shader_constants);
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            return;
        }

        context->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &shader_constants);
    }

    void release() {
        swap_chain->SetFullscreenState(FALSE, NULL);
        sh_vertex->Release();
        sh_pixel->Release();

        vertex_buffer->Release();
        index_buffer->Release();

        swap_chain->Release();
        back_buffer->Release();
        device->Release();
        context->Release();
    }

// P R I V A T E //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    HRESULT compile_shader(LPCWSTR file, LPCSTR entry_point, LPCSTR features, ID3DBlob** program) {
        *program = nullptr;
        ID3DBlob *program_code = nullptr, *error;
        HRESULT hr = D3DCompileFromFile(file, NULL, D3D_COMPILE_STANDARD_FILE_INCLUDE, entry_point, features, D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG | D3DCOMPILE_SKIP_OPTIMIZATION, 0, &program_code, &error);
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            if (error) {
                OutputDebugStringA((char*)error->GetBufferPointer());
                error->Release();
            }
            else {
            }
            if (program_code) { program_code->Release(); }
        }
        else { OutputDebugStringA("Shader compiled successfully\n"); }
        *program = program_code;
        return hr;
    }

    void init_pipeline() {
        ID3DBlob *pg_vertex, *pg_pixel;
        compile_shader(L"shaders.shader", "VShader", "vs_4_0", &pg_vertex);
        compile_shader(L"shaders.shader", "PShader", "ps_4_0", &pg_pixel);

        device->CreateVertexShader(pg_vertex->GetBufferPointer(), pg_vertex->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &sh_vertex);
        device->CreatePixelShader(pg_pixel->GetBufferPointer(), pg_pixel->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &sh_pixel);

        context->VSSetShader(sh_vertex, NULL, NULL);
        context->PSSetShader(sh_pixel, NULL, NULL);


        D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC ied[] = {
            {"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
            {"COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}
        };

        device->CreateInputLayout(ied, 2, pg_vertex->GetBufferPointer(), pg_vertex->GetBufferSize(), &layout);
        context->IASetInputLayout(layout);
    }

    // TODO - function that will build buffers if given a list of verts
    // and a list of indices. Perhaps this is a mesh_data structure?
    void init_graphics() {
        vertex vertices[] = {
            {0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f} },
            {0.45f, -0.5f, 0.0f, {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f} },
            {-0.45f, -0.5f, 0.0f, {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f} }
        };

        D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertex_buffer_description, index_buffer_description;
        ZeroMemory(&vertex_buffer_description, sizeof(vertex_buffer_description));
        ZeroMemory(&index_buffer_description, sizeof(index_buffer_description));

        vertex_buffer_description.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
        vertex_buffer_description.ByteWidth = sizeof(vertex) * 3;
        vertex_buffer_description.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
        vertex_buffer_description.CPUAccessFlags = 0;

        D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vertex_data;
        vertex_data.pSysMem = vertices;
        vertex_data.SysMemPitch = 0;
        vertex_data.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

        device->CreateBuffer(&vertex_buffer_description, &vertex_data, &vertex_buffer);

        unsigned int indices[] = { 0, 1, 2 };
        index_buffer_description.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
        index_buffer_description.ByteWidth = sizeof(unsigned int) * 3;
        index_buffer_description.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
        index_buffer_description.CPUAccessFlags = 0;

        D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA index_data;
        index_data.pSysMem = indices;
        index_data.SysMemPitch = 0;
        index_data.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

        device->CreateBuffer(&index_buffer_description, &index_data, &index_buffer);
    }

    void build_depth_stencil(unsigned int width, unsigned int height) {
        HRESULT hr;

        D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC descDepth;
        descDepth.Width = width;
        descDepth.Height = height;
        descDepth.MipLevels = 1;
        descDepth.ArraySize = 1;
        descDepth.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
        descDepth.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
        descDepth.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
        descDepth.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
        descDepth.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
        descDepth.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
        descDepth.MiscFlags = 0;
        hr = device->CreateTexture2D(&descDepth, NULL, &depth_stencil_buffer);

        D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC dsDesc;
        // Depth test parameters
        dsDesc.DepthEnable = true;
        dsDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
        dsDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;

        // Stencil test parameters
        dsDesc.StencilEnable = true;
        dsDesc.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
        dsDesc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;

        // Stencil operations if pixel is front-facing
        dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
        dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
        dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
        dsDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

        // Stencil operations if pixel is back-facing
        dsDesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
        dsDesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
        dsDesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
        dsDesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

        // Create depth stencil state
        device->CreateDepthStencilState(&dsDesc, &depth_stencil_state);

        D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC descDSV = {};
        descDSV.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
        descDSV.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
        descDSV.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;
        hr = device->CreateDepthStencilView(depth_stencil_buffer, // Depth stencil texture
            &descDSV, // Depth stencil desc
            &depth_stencil_view);
    }
} // end namespace
```

and my shader:

```
cbuffer buffer {
    matrix model;
    matrix view;
    matrix projection;
};

struct VOut
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};

VOut VShader(float4 position : POSITION, float4 color : COLOR)
{
    VOut output;

    output.position = mul(position, model);
    output.position = mul(output.position, view);
    output.position = mul(output.position, projection);
    output.color = color;
    return output;
}

float4 PShader(float4 position : SV_POSITION, float4 color : COLOR) : SV_TARGET
{
    return color;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Many possible reasons why something would not be rendered but if the difference is only in the matrix, here's some that I think might be most likely:

- Camera is too far (a triangle of size 1 in distance ~1732 with 45 degree FOV might simply be too small to see)
- You're looking at the triangle from the other side and culling is enabled (seems a bit unlikely though, since z<0 should be the right place for a viewpoint)
- Matrix multiplication might need to be done in the other order (by transposing the matrix/swapping `mul` arguments, depends on whether those are row/column-major matrices)